# Linking to another question in comment generates a second comment

Tags: support, comments

When I post a comment with a link to another question in the form 'http ://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820' (without the space after http), this link is displayed as 'stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820'. Some moments later, a second comment appears with the same contents but the link is displayed with the linked question's title. The second comment is attributed to me although I did not actually post it.

Example:  [Convert a base64 encoded string to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010277)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there some background processing that it not quite right?

Comment: When you vote to close as a duplicate, the system will add a comment to that effect on your behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have marked it as duplicate. So System posted it on your behalf.

Comment: yes, that's it. ok, my bad, I get it now.